# Creating A Linked List. C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes, user-input

I've tried creating linked list/node classes and I'm not sure where to go next. My attempts haven't went well because after creating the classes I'm just not sure what the next step is.

I'm trying to create a program that has a dinosaur node which saves information about the dinosaur such as id, species etc and I want to allow the user to create and remove dinosaurs from the list. So I need to allow the user to input data, I assume there's a way to make dino id get set automatically but I'm not to sure.

I've included the `LinkedList.cs` and the `Node.cs` so you can see where I'm going but I have no idea what to do within my program class to utilise the linked list and achieve what I'm trying to do.

Added `Program.cs` class incase that helps identify/show where I am within the program/what I need to do.

Linked List Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Text;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    public class LinkedList
    {

        private Node head;
        private int count;

        public LinkedList()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public bool Empty
        {
            get { return this.count == 0; }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.count; }
        }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get { return this.Get(index); }
        }

        public object Add(int index, object o)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (index > count)
                index = count;

            Node current = this.head;

            if (this.Empty || index == 0)
            {
                this.head = new Node(o, this.head);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                    current.Next = new Node(o, current.Next);
                }
            }
            count++;
            return o;
        }

        public object Add(object o)
        {
            return this.Add(count, o);
        }

        public object Remove(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return null;

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = count - 1;

            Node current = this.head;
            object result = null;

            if (index == 0)
            {
                result = current.Data;
                this.head = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; index < index - 1; i++) ;
                current = current.Next;

                result = current.Next.Data;
                current.Next = current.Next.Next;
            }

            count--;

            return result;

        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public int IndexOf(object o)
        {
            Node current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(o))
                    return i;

                current = current.Next;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public bool Contains(object o)
        {
            return this.IndexOf(o) >= 0;
        }

        public object Get(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return null;

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = this.count - 1;

            Node current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                current = current.Next;

            return current.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Node Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    public class Node
    {
        private object data;
        private Node next;
    private string DinoSpecies;
    private string DinoName;

        public Node(object data, Node next)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public object Data
        {
            get { return this.data; }
            set { this.data = value; }
        }

        public Node Next
        {
            get { return this.next; }
            set { this.next = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Program Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    class Program
    {

        class Dinosaur
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Classification;
            public char Sex;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();

            Dinosaur Dino1 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino1.Name = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
            Dino1.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino1.Sex = 'M';

            Dinosaur Dino2 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino2.Name = "Velociraptor";
            Dino2.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino2.Sex = 'F';

            Dinosaur Dino3 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino3.Name = "Procompsognathus";
            Dino3.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino3.Sex = 'M';

            void printList()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current Queue: ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + d.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Classification: " + d.Classification);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sex " + d.Sex);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Dino1.Name +  Dino1.Sex);
            }
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino1);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino2);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino3);
            printList();
            Console.WriteLine(DinoList.Count);


            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("E:/Work/Dinosaur.txt");
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
            {
                writer.Write(d.Name);
                writer.Write(d.Classification);
                writer.Write(d.Sex);
            }
            writer.Close();


            Console.WriteLine("Reading Back From File");
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead("E:/Work/Dinosaur.txt");
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file);
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Dinosaur d = new Dinosaur();
                d.Name = reader.ReadString();
                d.Classification = reader.ReadString();
                d.Sex = reader.ReadChar();
                DinoList.AddLast(d);
            }
            reader.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise? If no then why not to use the already provided `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: Yes it's some sort of exercise. I tried using ` LinkedList<T> ` previously but had no idea what I was doing with that either and I need to implement it without using the one already provided in C#. I followed a tutorial to create the linkedlist and node class now I'm just not sure how to use it to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `I'm just not sure how to use it to do what I'm trying to achieve`. OK, so what are you trying to achieve? Would a standard `List` not work? And normally, when you don't understand how something works, the general advice would not be 'try writing your own implentation' (unless the excercise is writing your own implentation)

Comment: I'm trying to get user input from the user for dinoName where dinoID would be set automatically that increments through 1>2>3 etc for each new dinosaur that would be created. I want the user to be able to decide where it is stored in the linked list so they can put it at the start, middle, end etc and they should also be able to remove from anywhere in the list. I'm tasked with using a LinkedList and implementing my own LinkedList if I didn't have to use it I wouldn't

Comment: The linked list seems fine. Just the Node: that should have a Dinosaur class as data instead of an unused object

Comment: So I should have an additional class within the node class that holds the values I want to take in for the dinosaur such as name etc. @HansKeﬆing

Comment: My guess this is one of annoying entry level tasks from programing courses here is an article with explanations https://dzone.com/articles/linked-list-implementation-in-c#:~:text=Linked%20List%20Implementation%20in%20C%23%201%20Insert%20Data,Key%20Value.%205%20Reverse%20a%20Singly%20Linked%20List. I would recommend you implement this using generic  arguments because they are important in C# and  not that hard to implement.

Comment: Yes agreed it's a very annoying task been struggling with it for the past 4 days, just been going round and round in circles I'll have a look at the link you provided hopefully that will help sort out some of my issues.

Comment: Once you get this working, change it to a generic type (i.e.  a `Yours.LinkedList<T>` that works with `Yours.Node<T>`). You'll be much happier with a generic list than with one that collects `object`s

Comment: For the purpose of this I can't use ` Yours.LinkedList<T. ` @Flydog57

Comment: I'm not saying "use the library-provided collection class". Im saying "when you write your own version (in the `Yours` namespace), have it collect instances of `T`, not instances of `object`. In addition to stronger type safety, you get better performance (no boxing and unboxing of value types) and possibly less stress on the garbage collector. Generic collection classes beat their non-generic brothers (/sisters) in every way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this, which hangs on user input and tries to do simple validation.  I made it a bit overly complex to demonstrate some options.

```
class Sample
{
    private static int index = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();

        while (true)
        {
            var dino = new Dinosaur();
            dino.Name = GetInput("Enter dino name (q to quit): ");
            if (dino.Name == "q" || dino.Name == "Q")
            {
                break;
            }

            dino.Classification = GetInput("Enter dino classification: ");
            char[] sexes = new char[] {'F', 'f', 'M', 'm'};
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter dino sex (M/F): ");
                dino.Sex = (char) Console.Read();
                if (sexes.Contains(dino.Sex))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            int inputIndex = default;
            while (true)
            {
                var indexString = GetInput($"Enter 0-index list position (max {DinoList.Count})");
                inputIndex = Convert.ToInt32(indexString);
                if (inputIndex <= DinoList.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            DinoList.Add(inputIndex, dino);
            index++;

            Console.WriteLine("Dinosaurs:");
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
            for (var i = 0; i < DinoList.Count; i++)
            {
                var dinosaur = (Dinosaur) DinoList.Get(i);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dinosaur.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Classification: " + dinosaur.Classification);
                Console.WriteLine("Sex: " + dinosaur.Sex);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetInput(string prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to make your `LinkedList` and `Node` into `LinkedList<T>` and `Node<T>` but they converted directly, so it's just a bit of typing.

Hope it helps!

Edit:  Add classes provided in question, modified to be generic.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    private object data;
    private Node<T> next;
    private string DinoSpecies;
    private string DinoName;

    public Node(object data, Node<T> next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
        set { this.data = value; }
    }

    public Node<T> Next
    {
        get { return this.next; }
        set { this.next = value; }
    }
}

public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private int count;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public bool Empty
    {
        get { return this.count == 0; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.count; }
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.Get(index); }
    }

    public object Add(int index, object o)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);
        if (index > count)
            index = count;
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        if (this.Empty || index == 0)
        {
            this.head = new Node<T>(o, this.head);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            {
                current = current.Next;
                current.Next = new Node<T>(o, current.Next);
            }
        }
        count++;
        return o;
    }

    public object Add(object o)
    {
        return this.Add(count, o);
    }

    public object Remove(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);
        if (this.Empty)
            return null;
        if (index >= this.count)
            index = count - 1;
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        object result = null;
        if (index == 0)
        {
            result = current.Data;
            this.head = current.Next;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; index < index - 1; i++) ;
            current = current.Next;
            result = current.Next.Data;
            current.Next = current.Next.Next;
        }
        count--;
        return result;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public int IndexOf(object o)
    {
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(o))
                return i;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public bool Contains(object o)
    {
        return this.IndexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    public object Get(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);
        if (this.Empty)
            return null;
        if (index >= this.count)
            index = this.count - 1;
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            current = current.Next;
        return current.Data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it does exactly what I'm looking to do unfortunately for the purpose of what I'm doing I have to create  the ` LinkedList ` and ` Node ` class without using the built in ` LinkedList<T> ` and ` Node<T> ` that are already built in C#

Comment: I think I understand.  What I'm saying is that your classes are good to go, just have to type <T> in a few places.  Once you change the class to public class LinkedList<T>, your IDE will probably tell you the other places to type it.  Hopefully :)  I ran the console application using our code together.

Comment: Yes but this is using the already implemented list in C#, I can't use it for the purpose of what I'm doing. If you could add both our codes combined that would be helpful though.

Comment: Ahh, I thought you'd written the LinkedList yourself?  All I did was edit what you pasted above.  I'll paste in the modified classes in case that's what you need.  I can't write a full LinkedList class from scratch though sorry